# getting value of initially hidden textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the value of a textbox which is initially **hidden through css** and is displayed using simple jquery... Now i want to get the value of the textbox that is initially hidden... the code is as below :

```
$("#reply_send").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#reply_name').val();
    alert(name);
});
```

but this returns `undefined`. How do i get to get that value ?

Comment: Are you disabling the text field? If so that could be an issue. Please post your html and css.

Comment: If the textbox is hidden you will not be able to get information from it. Perhaps, just before you hide it with jQuery, you can get the value and then hide it.

Comment: What? you can get the value of a textbox that is hidden...http://jsfiddle.net/vju25/

Comment: @jan267 If the click event is firing, it has to.

Comment: @Asad, no the click event is bound to `#reply_send` not `#reply_name`

Comment: which is **initially** hidden

Comment: @Gabe You're right, speed read and missed that.

Comment: @pmandell Doesn't matter when it's hidden, you can get the value from it. It still exists in the DOM.

Comment: My bad @Gabe, I had just had a discussion with someone about getting image dimensions from images that were not yet loaded. I was still in that mode and mis-spoke.

Comment: @Gabe It depends actually on how he is hiding his control. if it is a server side control with visible set to false then it doesn't exist in the DOM until the server sets its visibility to true. if he is using CSS to set the display=none then it is in the DOM. so without his html and css it is hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: @Mike_OBrien, uh perhaps you should read, the OP states that the textbox is hidden via css. Thanks for the lesson tho.

Comment: @Gabe: missed that part but the point still stands. saying something is hidden, even specifying through css, leaves too much up to interpretation. seeing his mark up would make this question much easier to clearly asnwer. And you are very welcome.

Comment: @Mike_OBrien, So you miss the key fact of the question yet still want to argue that it's a server side control? Perhaps you should get more experience on the site before trying to preach.

Comment: @Mike_OBrien - There's a good chance this isn't server side controls since the [users history indicates he's only working in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1223654/user1223654?tab=questions&sort=newest). I don't see a standing point.

Comment: wow slow down. whos arguing what? I offered an opinion of why his code might not be working since i've run into this in the past and avoiding the visibility attribute of server side contols fixed it for me. was it wrong? not at all. was it wrong in this case? maybe. but all it showed was that he didn't post enough information for his question to be answered. if he had posted his HTML then there would have been no confusion. you really shouldn't get all bent out of shape over a single comment...

Comment: You didn't even read the first sentence of the OP properly, so that's why I was pointing out your invalid assumptions of a server side control, which is clearly not the culprit.

Comment: guys there actually was an html error . its fixed . thankyou very much

Comment: @Gabe: so lets break this down, take my examples out of my first comment and lets look at the main point. Which was, its probably an error in his HTML or CSS but without seeing it we couldn't know what he was doing. and low and behold! it was an error in his HTML that he didn't post. so in hindsight your comments were less helpful to the OP than mine were even with the false assumptions tied to the examples. funny how that worked out isn't it?

Comment: @Mike_OBrien, I didn't make any assumptions about the question. I'm not sure if it's funny or sad that you think you were more helpful when you couldn't even accurately read the first sentence of the question.

Comment: @Gabe: and your reponse of "it does work" was helpful? at least my interpretation of the question raised the point of it being something in the HTML/CSS which you never even mentioned as a possible cause. No, you are right your answer was Way more helpful. My mistake.

Comment: Considering I was replying to a comment made that was made previous to mine, again you need to work on your reading skills.

Comment: @Gabe: So was the problem something in the HTML/CSS? neither of which you even mention in any of your condescending comments? my skim reading skills aside, at least I offered a few examples of how the markup could cause seemingly odd DOM behavior and asked the OP to give more info so we could HELP HIM with the problem.  Commenting on a previous comment is fine but you could have possibly mentioned why the JS wasn't working. Then you would have been at least attempting to be helpful. bashing me for skim reading doesn't change the fact that my point(check the html) was relevant to the question

Comment: @Mike_OBrien - How about you write a book about it

Comment: @gabe nah there's already a faq for how users should answer/comment on questions so writing a book would be redundant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an HTML error as this seems to be working fine. Assuming your textarea has an id of **reply_name**, then you will be able to retrieve the value with **$('#reply_name').val();**.

check this out: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EbhaZ/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#show').click(function(){
        $('div').show();        
    });
    $('#reply_send').click(function(){
      var name= $('#reply_name').val();
      alert(name);            
    });
});​
```

Comment: How does this actually answer the question?

Comment: @JonStirling, My thoughts exactly.

Comment: @Gabe I've already removed my upvote and comment, no harm done.